# Issue with returning the table of variables when writing a function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R that 1) produce an error if input is not a data frame 2) generate summary for numerical data (median, IQR, no. of non-missing observation) 3) summary for categorical data (no. of non-missing observation, % for each level/category).

I converted the integer variables to factor variables before writing the function.

```
function(x) {
if(is.data.frame(df$x)) {
    stop("Input is not a data frame")
}
# Summary table of the numerical variables
if(is.numeric(df$x) & !is.factor(df$x)) {
    table_numeric <- summarise(df, sum(!is.na(x)), median(x,na.rm=T), quantile(x,probs=c(0.25),na.rm=T), quantile(x,probs=c(0.75),na.rm=T) )
}
# Summary table of the categorical variables
if(is.factor(df$x) & !is.numeric(df$x)) {
    table_categorical <- table(df$x)
    table_factor <- summarise(df, prop.table(table_categorical)*100, table(x,exclude=NULL))
}

# Return the table of the variables
return(c("Summary of numerical data" = table_numeric, "Summary of categorical data" = table_factor))}
```

I tried the programme on individual codes without the loops and it works, but not so sure what went wrong along the way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sample dataset
[Dataset of what I was supposed to summarise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJxN2.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset? Also how do you expect the function to behave? Maybe provide couple of inputs and corresponding expected output for them.

Comment: I do not understand the logic here. It's a function of `x`. Well, fine. Why is `x` never used within the function? And then you test if `df$x` is a data.frame? And later on, if `df$x` is a numeric vector or factor? How can you expect both? Also, I don't see a loop.

Comment: I agree with @Roland it is hard to understand the logic between `df` and `x`. Additionally in the first if, you are looking if `df$x` is a data.frame and if it is you are stopping the function because "Input is not a data frame", it should be the inverse

Comment: The function should take the input of a data frame and a vector of columns and produce tables to summarise the data.  

I have to call the function twice.  Once, to generate the error message and secondly, to input variables age, hgb, hct to get the tables.